# grails confirmation email flow

Tags: security, grails

I'm going to develop an email confirmation flow with grails. I'm using the REST security plugin and this is the flow I've in my mind:

1. from browser: POST /auth/register passing username, password and email
2. server side: create a new user with ROLE_NOT_CONFIRMED
3. server side: automatically log user in and generate a new access-token
4. async server side: send an email with confirmation url like GET /auth/confirm/*username*/*access-token*
5. user mail client: click on confirmation link
6. server side: check username and access_token as created in step 2
7. server side: if step 6 is ok, update user role to ROLE_USER

do you see any security issues?

Comment: Aside from step 3 (I'm not really sure why you need to log the user in at all), this is more or less how the Spring Security UI plugin accomplishes the "forgotten password" scenario. I'm not saying it should be taken as security gospel, but that is a pretty good endorsement of this type of workflow.

Comment: logging the user in with a ROLE_NOT_CONFIRMED can be usefull to authorize him to call some services like "resend confirmation link"

Comment: I didn't think about that. Good call. I like it. As I stated before, I don't really see anything wrong with this approach as similar approaches are used very often.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/RegistrationCode.groovy